# ¿Porque el "delete" no funciona como se espera ? Java, Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

La credencial simplemente no se borra, ¿ que estoy haciendo mal ?

Estoy debuggeando y la credencial que quiero borrar si existe, más cuando hace el "delete" no se borra.

Método del controlador:

```
   @Autowired
    private CredentialDao credentialDao;
@RequestMapping(value = "/fisicHost/{id}/credentials", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteCredential(@PathVariable(value = "id") String credId){
    String[] parts = credId.split("-");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    Credential c = credentialDao.getCredentialById(id);
    credentialDao.delete(c);
    return "justreturnsomething";
}
```

Clase CredentialDAO, método "delete":

```
@Override
public void delete(Credential credential) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.delete(credential);
    session.close();
}
```

Js del front-end que hace el request:

```
$("#credentialsTable").on('click',"button[id^='del-']",  (e) => {
    var credentialId = e.target.id;
        console.log('credId' + credentialId);
        $.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials", data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Debuggeando en IntelliJ veo que la credencial que deseo borrar es la correcta, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego por consola me imprime el "justreturnsomething" pero no me borra la credencial de la base de datos ...

Foto de la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la credencial que quiero borrar es la que tiene el ID 3 !!!

Comment: ¿En la consola del IDE, el log del servidor no te muestra ningún mensaje?

Comment: No, no muestra nada ... lo raro es que en el modo debugg la credencial que estoy queriendo borrar está bien y los atributos de la misma también .... pero no se borra de la BD

Comment: Lo único raro que veo en la consola de debugg es esto: sessionFactory=nul .... tendrá algo que ver para que no se conecte a la base de datos o algo así ?? Igual es raro porque en la clase la tengo como autowired

Comment: Igual es raro porque la línea anterior al delete si hace el getCredentialById bien así que la conexión no debe estar mal ...

Comment: Has probado a hacer un session.flush() tras el delete? Suelo trabajar con transacciones y no necesito hacer nada de esto manualmente, pero tu implementación quizá las necesita

Comment: No, que es el session.flush () ?